# My demo django project doesn't start server after a restarting command prompt

Tags: django

I have created demo django project, now I cant run the server. I'm getting "ImportError: Couldn't import Django" I dont know what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you forgotten to install Django as pip install Django, you mush have created the project first of all so perhaps your virtual environment wasn't open. Please edit the post with traceback.

Comment: Did you create the project and run it without a virtualenv? Or perhaps you forgot to install django inside the virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

You must install Django. The error is about this. Maybe you installed django on a virtual environment and you have deactivated it?